# Border radius with ems?

Tags: css

Is it better for responsive design to set a border-radius in ems rather than px?

Ive read that column and media query widths are better as ems than pixels for a more responsive design, however ive never heard of someone using ems for border radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

em is always better for responsive design and you can convert it here http://pxtoem.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use ems for border radius , is it better for responsive than px ? , eh debatable .. because its not always the case , when your screen is small or relatively large it will look not look so good or aesthetic , but responsive design wise , its better to use ems than px